# Ingreso Sistema Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Saludos mi problema es el siguiente: Estoy haciendo un sistema con login con Angular, el cual esta enfocado a llamadas de Api, cuando realizo el primer ingreso al sistema, hago la llamada al Api de Login y me devuelve datos pero no ingresa al sistema, tengo que recargar la pagina para volver a realizar el ingreso y ahi si me deja ingresar, entonces no se porque es que al ingresar la primera vez no me permite, pero después ya me deja tengo tiempo buscando solucion pero no encuentro, les agradeceria mucho su ayuda.

```
onSubmit(form:NgForm){
console.log(form);
if(form.invalid){return;}
this.activapopup=true;

this.auth.loginP(this.usuario)
.subscribe(resp =>{
  this.activapopup=false;
  if(resp['data'].estadoUsuario=='RESET_REQUIRED'){
    this.popupResetCont=true;
  }else if(resp['data'].estadoUsuario=="FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD"){
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/actualizar-contrasena');
    localStorage.setItem('clvtemp',this.usuario.password);
  }else if(resp['data'].estadoUsuario=='CHANGE_PASSWORD'){
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/login/contrasena-actualizar');
  }else if(resp['data'].estadoUsuario=='CONFIRMED'){
    if(this.registrReco){
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/registro-reco');
    }else{
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/bienvenido');
    }

  }
  console.log(resp['data']);
  if(this.recordarme){
    localStorage.setItem('email',this.usuario.email);
  }
},(err) =>{
  console.log(err.error);
  this.errorlog=true;
  this.erroru=true;
  this.error=err.error['message'];
  console.log(this.errorlog);
  Swal.close();
  this.activapopup=false;
});
```

}

el campo "estadoUsuario" cuando me retorna "FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD" me indica cuando el usuario ingresa por primera vez al sistema y ahi se debe ir a actualizar contraseña pero no lo realiza la primera vez, cuando recargo la pagina si lo realiza.

Answer (score 0):

Usa:

```
this.router.navigate(['/actualizar-contrasena'])
```